# What are the essential layers in the design of a MOM capacitor in Cadence?

Tags: capacitor, integrated-circuit, cadence

I need to design a custom-designed MOM capacitor.
I have looked into the layout of a MOM capacitor in 65nm CMOS technology, and I am a bit confused. There are many layers that I don't understand the purpose of them (except for metal layers which I am sure about their functionality). Could you please explain which layers are necessary for the design of a MOM capacitor?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Can you add a 1) reference image and 2) a list of layers as well as 3) the source material you are referring to ? It will be difficult to answer without having and image or a reference link.

Comment: Hi @AJN . Thanks for your response. I'm unable to do that because I'm using a technology file. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to disclose the information. There are many dummy layers. There is a N-Well layer, and a N-plus layer. There is also an oxide layer. By the way they use both CTM/BTM layers and Metal layers which is confusing to me.